# Make: stop compilation on error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, babeljs

I'm starting to use GNU Make as my frontend build tool, and most things work great. Only thing annoying is that compilation doesn't seem to stop when one of the steps reaches an error. The relevant portion of the Makefile:

```
js_files=$(filter-out $(ignore_js),$(wildcard \
             js/ll/*.js js/ll/**/*.js))
ignore_js=js/ll/dist% js/ll/%.min.js

%.min.js: %.js
    @echo ">>> Uglifying $?"
    @$(BABELJS) $(BABELJSFLAGS) $? | $(UGLIFYJS) --source-map $(UGLIFYJSFLAGS) > $@

min_js_files=$(js_files:%.js=%.min.js)
main.js: $(min_js_files)
    @echo ">>> Concatenating JavaScript"
    mkdir -p $(DIST_DIR)
    cat $^ > $(DIST_DIR)$@

prod: main.js clean
```

The output I get from running `make prod` looks something like this:

```
>>> Uglifying js/ll/DateEx.js              
SyntaxError: js/ll/DateEx.js: Invalid number (22:36)
  20 |     day = today.getDate();          
  21 |   }                                 
> 22 |   return new Date(year, month, day, 01, 0, 0);
     |                                     ^
  23 | }
  24 |
  25 | function newDateS(s)
>>> Uglifying js/ll/Anonymization.js
>>> Uglifying js/ll/DummyStorage.js
(...)
```

I have the impression that this happens because the steps run in parallel, but I know nothing about Make to back that up. How can I have compilation stop when one of the steps returns non-zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is the well-established default behavior of Make. Something in your build chain is not properly setting a nonzero exit code on failure, or you are masking it out.

In particular, the exit code from a shell pipeline is always the exit code from the final command in the pipeline.  In other words, any error from `BABELJS` in your recipe will be lost.

Maybe refactor to not use a pipe, perhaps something like this:

```
%.min.js: %.js.tmp
    $(UGLIFYJS) --source-map $(UGLIFYJSFLAGS) <$< >$@
%.js.tmp: %.js
    $(BABELJS) $(BABELJSFLAGS) $< >$@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.js.tmp
```

The use of a temporary file is a bit of a wart, and the choice whether to use a separate recipe for the first step is kind of arbitrary.  I prefer this style because it better adheres to the spirit of Make (explicitly declare dependencies, let Make keep track) but if you want fine-grained control over the flow, you could go the other way.

I also removed the `@` prefix from the `BABELJS` rule.  This is a bit of a private crusade of mine -- littering your Makefile with these makes debugging hard, and the proper solution if you want peace and quiet is to use `make -s`.